# Aliasing usecase in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, alias

I am new to elastic search, I have through some blogs and bit of documentation to understand it. All other concepts like Node, Cluster, Index, Documents, Fields, Sharding are clear to me but i am finding difficulty in understanding the alias concept in elastic search. I have seen previous stack overflow answers but was not able to relate to the concept of aliasing. Can someone elaborate on this.

Answer (score 0):

an alias is like an index "link" that can point to one or more indices

eg `index-alias` can point to;

- `index0`
- `index0` **and** `index1`

use cases would be for using an easy to remember index name to query, rather than something like `index0-<randomid>`, to be able to easily query multiple indices, or to even allow the index under the alias to be rotated between other indices in the cluster

Comment: here you mentioned that index-alias can point to more than one index also, in the above case it is pointing to 2 index0 and index1. so when we query with the alias, how would it know that we want to get index0 or index1 because while query we will only pass the alias.

Comment: in that case Elasticsearch assumes you want to query both indices. if you don't, then you need to directly query the index you want